# Replacing two toggle switches that are linked with the same grounding wire

Tags: electrical, grounding

The bathroom light switches are wired to independent red and black switches but are connected together by a copper grounding wire that is looped around one screw and then terminates on the second toggle. Can I take both switches out and just duplicate the setup with the new toggles? How do I know I bought the right switches?

Answer (score 1):

If the switches have the same number of screws you should be all set. Loop the ground as it is now you should be OK. If there are three screws on one or more of the switches look for the one screw that is identified, the screw will be a different color. Be sure to take pictures before you remove anything.